# how to add bootstrap 3 and jQuery to slate

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

i am new in shopify and i have a problem.

i need to add bootstrap 3 to my template and i have a problem with jquery 
i have this error
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

its my theme.js code

```
import 'lazysizes/plugins/object-fit/ls.object-fit';
import 'lazysizes/plugins/parent-fit/ls.parent-fit';
import 'lazysizes/plugins/rias/ls.rias';
import 'lazysizes/plugins/bgset/ls.bgset';
import 'lazysizes';
import 'lazysizes/plugins/respimg/ls.respimg';

import jQuery from 'jquery'

import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap";


import '../../styles/theme.scss';
import '../../styles/theme.scss.liquid';
```

and it is my slate.config.js

```
/* eslint-disable */

// Configuration file for all things Slate.
// For more information, visit https://github.com/Shopify/slate/wiki/Slate-Configuration

const path = require('path');

    module.exports = {
      'cssVarLoader.liquidPath': ['src/snippets/css-variables.liquid'],
      'webpack.extend': {
        resolve: {
          alias: {
            jquery: path.resolve('./node_modules/jquery'),
            'lodash-es': path.resolve('./node_modules/lodash-es'),
          },
        },
      },
    };
```

i worked with webpack and in other project i use this code and i have no problem

```
  plugins:[
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ]
```

Comment: Why would you use an old and discontinued CSS framework like BootStrap 3 when there is version 4? If you are bothering to use modern JS, why use retired CSS?

Comment: i have a html template and that used bootstrap 3, But my main problem is jQuery and how to use it with import and doesn't recognized by any other script

Comment: Another good reason is Shopify currently only supports Sass 3.2